# how to display the checked values in jsp page to a servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am writing a application which involves a dynamic table  in jsp with check boxes at each row. once i check in the check boxes at the rows, the selected values should be displayed in the next page as a servvlet and i should send the servlet to the server or DB. Can anyone pls help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In your servlet you can obtain the selected check boxes using

```
String[] values = request.getParameterValues("checkboxGroup");
```

Your input types could be something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup" value="3" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Populate Table in jsp to show checkbox with each row

HTML should be following.

```
<input TYPE=checkbox name="teamName" VALUE="India"> India
```

Now POST it to some servlet and there use following code to retrieve selected checkboxes's value

```
 String team[] = request.getParameterValues("teamName");
```